# onreadystatechange in AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I have a problem with the onreadystatechange when i make ajax request, it used to call the function but
now it does not call the processRequest.

I am not sure if I edited something or what..Can sombody help..

```
function createAjaxObject(url, callback) 
{
    /// @par Implementation 
    var req = init();
  req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    /// @brief  Creates a ajax object based on the runnunf browser    
    function init() 
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    /// @brief Checks if request is complete and HTTP call is successful
    function processRequest () 
    {   

        /// readyState of 4 signifies request is complete

        if (req.readyState == 4){

            /// status of 200 signifies sucessful HTTP call
            if (req.status == 200){
                if (callback) 
                callback(req.responseXML);
            }
        }
    }

     this.doPost = function(param) {

             if (req.readyState == 4) {

        /// make a HTTP GET request to the URL asynchronously
        req.open("POST",url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-length",param.length);
        req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        req.send(param);

        }
    }
}
```

thanks,

Comment: You're never calling the `doPost()` method.

Comment: Your code does not ever initiate an actual HTTP transaction; there's no call to `.send()`. Also, your code assigns the "doPost" function to `this.doPost`, but `this` is probably not the correct thing. Basically it looks like random code patched together without any concept of how anything works.

Comment: try using jquery or prototype. it's a lot easier to use and has the browser check already built in

Comment: its actually the creation of the whole ajax object and the processing of the request. tha actual call is not there but its used as how @T.J. Crowder described it below. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if (req.readyState == 4) {
```

...(and the corresponding `}`) shouldn't be in the function you're assigning to `this.doPost`. E.g.:

```
this.doPost = function(param) {

    /// make a HTTP GET request to the URL asynchronously
    req.open("POST",url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-length",param.length);
    req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    req.send(param);
};
```

I'm assuming the way you use that is:

```
var obj = new createAjaxObject(url, callback);
obj.doPost();
```

...because the code quoted never actually calls the function that does the post, but rather just assigns it to a property on `this`. The usual place you assign properties to `this` is within a constructor function, hence my using `new` above.

(BTW: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript code is to use initial caps on functions that are used as constructors, e.g. `CreateAjaxObject` [or better yet, just `AjaxObject`] rather than `createAjaxObject`.)

There are a *bunch* of other changes I'd make to that code, but I think that's the minimum.

---

Side note: I'd recommend using a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over a *lot* of browser differences and provide a huge amount of well-tested utility functionality, letting you focus on what you actually need to do.

Comment: hi @T.J Crowder you're correct i call the function above by that.. and im using new..

Comment: Crowder THANK YOU!! yes i found it, that code should not be there.. thanks a lot man!

Comment: @tinks: Good deal, glad that helped.