# JSON eval in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a problem regarding return data using JSON. How do i get the data returned from my php if i use JSON? Just like when you use responseXML, the response is XML, so in the callback you can go:

```
function callbackFunc(){
var str = responseXML.getElementsByTagName('tagOne')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
..
}
```

If I am using JSON how do i access the return data?

Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON) object in modern browsers.

You won't need to mess about with entity tags, you can simply `JSON.parse(responseData)` and the structure will be available in an Object.

```
function callbackFunc(responseData){
  var data = JSON.parse(responseData);
  console.log(data);
..
}
```

Comment: is the return value passed on the callback in javascript?
I really cant seem to get this json. does it work similarly with 
responseXML?

Comment: This really depends on how you received responseXML to begin with. I don't know what your `callbackFunc` definition is, or where it's being invoked from, I was just trying to make as much logical sense as I could. Are you using jQuery to handle your AJAX request?

Comment: thanks @Morgon, im not using jQuery actually, I am using the same codes that I used in invoking the call with responseXML reply. Im using this obecjt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513377/onreadystatechange-in-ajax-not-working

Comment: and then in my php i save my data in an array and then json_encode() it.. the response I get shows in the response tab of the firebug.. goes something like ["data1","data2",...] I tried your suggestion, but in my callback function, I cannot get a value, its null... or am i just pretty confused with this json thing..

Comment: Ah, going old-school. I see the issue - the `XMLHttpRequest` object has a property called `responseXML` that is the XML-formatted response. You don't need that - just use `req.responseText`. I would strongly suggest moving to [jQuery](http://jquery.org), as much of the AJAX stuff (and your Javascript code in general) will be greatly simplified and cleaner.

Comment: its there... thanks a lot.. yeah kinsa old school. you think its better if i use jquery instead?... oh ok... thanks @Morgon

Comment: Exponentially better. :) (Also, please don't forget to mark this as the answer if you're satisfied!)